# How to xor 2 hexadecimal inputs?

Tags: xor

I have 2 files: 1.txt and 2.txt, both containing hex characters.

```
1.txt : AFCD271E1EF7B1C3
2.txt : AD6DD9F49F562AF0
```

I need a command linux to get file "3.txt" with result of xor-ing both data contents of 1.txt and 2.txt.

E.g.:

```
3.txt : 2A0FEEA81A19B33
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: someone did the app for you :http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/xorfiles.html
next time please be more specific about what prog. language you want or what os.

Comment: i m newer to this domain and i need your help

Comment: firstly the xorfiles is .exe and me need linux command
second when i try to do this witht his program the result is not in hexdecimal

Answer (score 0):

Create xorfiles script,chmod +x xorfiles,xorfiles 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt

```
#!/bin/bash
file1=$(echo| cat $1)
file2=$(echo | cat $2)


#xor $file1 $file2

function  xor()
{
        local res=(`echo "$1" | sed "s/../0x& /g"`)
        shift 1
        while [[ "$1" ]]; do
            local one=(`echo "$1" | sed "s/../0x& /g"`)
            local count1=${#res[@]}
            if [ $count1 -lt ${#one[@]} ]
            then
                  count1=${#one[@]}
            fi
            for (( i = 0; i < $count1; i++ ))
            do
                  res[$i]=$((${one[$i]:-0} ^ ${res[$i]:-0}))
            done
            shift 1
        done
        printf "%02x" "${res[@]}"
}

echo $(xor $file1 $file2)
```

Result:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-137:~$ ./xorfiles ./1.txt ./2.txt
02a0feea81a19b33
```